# при скроле верх убрать класс

Tags: jquery

Есть у меня код который при скроле вниз добавляет класс, но не получается если вернутся на самых верх удалить этот класс, header у меня фиксированный может быть из за этого?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var target = $('.mid-header');
var winHeight = $(window).height();
var heihgtTopToElement = $(".mid-header").offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
 
                   
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowpos = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ( windowpos => heihgtTopToElement ) {
        $(".mid-header").addClass("active_nav");
    } else {
        $(".mid-header").removeClass("active_nav");
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте код ниже, у меня он работает прекрасно. Header тоже фиксированный

```
/* Fixed header */
let header = $(".mid-header");
let headerH = header.innerHeight();
let scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

checkScroll(scrollPos, headerH)

$(window).on("scroll resize", function() {
    let headerH = header.innerHeight();
    scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    checkScroll(scrollPos, headerH)
});

function checkScroll(scrollPos, headerH) {
    if(scrollPos > headerH) {
        header.addClass("active_nav");
    } else {
        header.removeClass("active_nav")
    }
}
```

Кстати, зачем создавать переменную target, но не использовать её?)

Comment: спасибо работает) да я чужой код просто редактировал, так и осталось